# SESSION Issue in Zencart

Tags: php, mysql, zen-cart

I have an issue related to session. I am using lampp on my system.
The issue is mainly with my local system while everything is working fine on server.

I am using Zencart CMS.

When I am adding a product to my cart, the code works fine and I get a message that the product has been added to the cart but when I go to the shopping cart page it shows empty cart.

Same is the issue with my login page. I am not able to login in my E-commerce website and getting an error as "Security error".

Does anyone know why system is creating a new session id whenever I am refreshing my page?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of items to check first.

1. go to your sessions area in the config area and check to see if the
   Recreate Session is enabled. Also check on the cookies as well.
2. The force ssl session id section may need adjustment as well.

The live site is not the same settings as the local. 
You will also want to explicitly set your session timeout session.gc_maxlifetime